# Why is (1-x)(1+x) preferred to (1-x^2)?

Tags: floating-point

I was looking at a runtime library implementation of `arcsin` which was implemented by calculating:

```
ArcTan(X, Sqrt(1 - X*X))
```

However, the code that calculated `1 - X*X` actually evaluated `(1-X)*(1+X)`. Is there a good reason for preferring the latter? I suspect that the latter reduces round-off inaccuracy for `X` close to zero, but I cannot reason why that would be so.

Comment: yes, you are understanding correctly. It is about round-off accuracy.

Comment: Not fully related with your particular case, but with logarithmic calculations such conversion may be extremely useful: `log(1-x*x)` will fail (i.e. loose precision) if x is near zero (`1E-12`, for example), while `log(1-x)+log(1+x)` will not fail. That, however, relies on logarithm specific property of summation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The derivative of `ArcTan(X, Sqrt(1-X*X))` with respect to X is `1/Sqrt(1-X*X)`. This goes to infinity as |X| goes to 1. Therefore, when X is near 1 or -1, any error in evaluation has a huge effect on the result. Thus, it is critical that evaluation minimize error in these cases.

When X is near 1, evaluation of `1-X` has no error (in IEEE 754 or any good floating-point system, because the scale of the result is such that its least significant bit is at least as low as the least significant bit in 1 or X, so the exact mathematical result has no bits outside the available significand bits). Since `1-X` is exact, consider the effect of the error in `1+X` by considering the derivative of `ArcTan(X, Sqrt((1-X)*(1+X+e))` with respect to e, where e is the error introduced in the `1+X` operation. The derivative is, when X is near 1 and e is small, approximately -1/10. (Taking the derivative with Maple and substituting 1 for x yields `-1/(sqrt(4+2e)*(5+2e))`. Then substituting 0 for e yields -1/10.) Thus, the error in `1+X` is not critical.

Therefore, evaluating the expression as `ArcTan(X, Sqrt((1-X)*(1+X))` is a good way to evaluate it.

The situation is symmetric for X near -1. (`1+X` has no error, and `1-X` is not critical.)

Conversely, if we consider the error in `X*X`, the derivative of `ArcTan(X, Sqrt(1-X*X+e))` with respect to e is, when X is near 1, approximately -1/(2*sqrt(e)*(1+e)), so it is large when e is small. So a small error in evaluating `X*X` will cause a large error in the result, when X is near 1.

---

Ask Pascal Cuoq points out, when evaluating a function f(x), we are generally interested in minimizing the relative error in the final result. And, as I have pointed out, the errors that occur during calculation are generally relative errors in intermediate results due to floating-point rounding. I was able to ignore this in the above because I was considering the function when X is near 1, so both the intermediate values under consideration (1+X and X*X) and the final value had magnitudes near 1, so dividing the values by those magnitudes would not change anything significantly.

However, for completeness, I examined the situation more closely. In Maple, I wrote `g := arctan(x, sqrt((1-x*x*(1+e0))*(1+e1))*(1+e2))`, thus allowing for relative errors e0, e1, and e2 in the calculations of `x*x`, `1-x*x`, and the `sqrt`, respectively, and I wrote `h:= arctan(x, sqrt((1-x)*(1+x)*(1+e0))*(1+e2))` for the alternative. Note that e0 in this case combines the three errors in `1-x`, `1+x`, and the multiplication of them; the full error term could be `(1+ea)*(1+eb)*(1+ec)`, but this is effectively `1+e0` with a larger possible range for e0.

Then I examined the derivatives of these functions with respect to (one at a time) e0, e1, and e2 divided by abs(f(x)), where `f` was the ideal function, `arctan(x, sqrt(1-x*x))`. E.g., in Maple, I examined `diff(g, e0) / abs(f(x))`. I did not perform a full analytic evaluation of these; I examined the values for some values of x near 0 and near 1 and for values of e0, e1, and e2 at one of their limits, -2<sup>-54</sup>.

For x near 0, the values were all of magnitude about 1 or less. That is, any relative error in calculation resulted in a similar relative error in the result, or less.

For x near 1, the values with the derivatives of e1 and e2 were tiny, about 10<sup>-8</sup> or less. However, the values with the derivatives of e0 were hugely different for the two methods. For the `1-x*x` method, the value was about 2•10<sup>7</sup> (using x = 1-2<sup>-53</sup>). For the `(1-x)*(1+x)` method, the value was about 5•10<sup>-9</sup>.

In summary, the two methods do not differ much near x = 0, but the `(1-x)*(1+x)` method is significantly better near x = 1.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote the program below in order to obtain some empirical results for single-precision.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long double d1, d2, rel1, rel2;
float i1, i2;
int main() {
  float f;
  for (f = nextafterf(0, 2); f <= 1; f = nextafterf(f, 2))
    {
      long double o = 1.0L - ((long double)f * f);
      float r1 = (1 - f) * (1 + f);
      float r2 = 1 - f * f;
      long double c1 = fabsl(o - r1);
      long double c2 = fabsl(o - r2);
      if (c1 > d1) d1 = c1;
      if (c2 > d2) d2 = c2;
      if (c1 / o > rel1) rel1 = c1 / o, i1 = f;
      if (c2 / o > rel2) rel2 = c2 / o, i2 = f;
    }

  printf("(1-x)(1+x) abs:%Le  relative:%Le\n", d1, rel1);
  printf("1-x*x      abs:%Le  relative:%Le\n\n", d2, rel2);

  printf("input1: %a 1-x:%a 1+x:%a (1-x)(1+x):%a o:%a\n", i1, 1-i1, 1+i1, (1-i1)*(1+i1), (double)(1 - ((long double)i1 * i1)));
  printf("input2: %a x*x:%a 1-x*x:%a o:%a\n", i2, i2*i2, 1 - i2*i2, (double)(1 - ((long double)i2 * i2)));
}
```

A few remarks:

- I used 80-bit `long double` to compute meta-data. This is not enough to precisely represent the error made for all values of `x`, but I fear the program would become prohibitively slow with higher precision.
- The reference value `o` is computed as `1.0L - ((long double)f * f)`. This is always the nearest `long double` number to the real result, because `(long double)f * f` is exact (see, already it seems that the form `1 - x*x` can sometimes be better :) ).

I obtained the results below:

```
(1-x)(1+x) abs:8.940394e-08  relative:9.447410e-08
1-x*x      abs:4.470348e-08  relative:8.631498e-05

input1: 0x1.6a046ep-1 1-x:0x1.2bf724p-2 1+x:0x1.b50238p+0 (1-x)(1+x):0x1.0007bep-1 o:0x1.0007bc6a305ep-1
input2: 0x1.ffe96p-1 x*x:0x1.ffd2cp-1 1-x*x:0x1.6ap-12 o:0x1.69f8007p-12
```

According to these results, `1 - x*x` has better absolute accuracy and `(1-x)*(1+x)` has **much** better relative accuracy. Floating-point is all about relative accuracy (the entire system is designed to allow relatively accurate representation of small and large values), so the latter form is preferred.

EDIT: Computing the final error makes more sense, as illustrated in Eric's answer. A subexpression in an expression such as `ArcTan(X, Sqrt(1 - X*X))` could have been chosen not because of its better accuracy overall but because it was accurate where it mattered most. Adding the lines below to the body of the loop:

```
  long double a = atan2l(f, sqrtl(o));
  float a1 = atan2f(f, sqrtf(r1));
  float a2 = atan2f(f, sqrtf(r2));
  long double e1 = fabsl(a - a1);
  long double e2 = fabsl(a - a2);
  if (e1 / a > ae1) ae1 = e1 / a, i1 = f;
  if (e2 / a > ae2) ae2 = e2 / a, i2 = f;
```

It might make as much sense to use `atan2l(f, sqrtf(r1))` because I do not have the exact same function `ArcTan` as your system. Anyway, with these caveats, for the complete expression, the maximum relative error on the interval [-1 … 1] is 1.4e-07 for the (1-x)(1+x) version and 5.5e-7 for the 1-x<sup>2</sup> version.

Comment: Tangent: A value of `float f` for which `1 - (long double)f * f)` is more accurate than `(1 - (long double)f) * (1 + (long double)f)` is `0x1.000002p-65`. The former is the correctly rounded `long double` approximation to the mathematical result because it has to be (`1.0L`), the latter evaluates to `0xf.fffffffffffffffp-4`.

Comment: You should consider the error in the final result, `ArcTan(X, Sqrt(1-X*X))`, not just an intermediate result.

Comment: The two-argument arctangent function is in C as `atan2(y, x)` and returns the arc tangent of y/x, using the signs of both arguments to determine the quadrant.

Comment: Converting the code to measure errors in the final results, by inserting `o = atan2l(f, sqrtl(o));` after the initial calculation of `o`, and similarly `r1 = atan2f(f, sqrtf(r1));` and `r2 = atan2f(f, sqrtf(r2));` yields “(1-x)(1+x) abs:1.146906e-07  relative:1.434818e-07” and “1-x*x      abs:8.559781e-07  relative:5.514648e-07”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Done. If I did not make a mistake, it turns out that only looking at the derivative of ArcTan does not provide a view of the final relative accuracy as representative as I would have expected. It matters proportionally less that |f(x+e)-f(x)| is large when |f(x)| is large.

Comment: I mean, the relative accuracy of `1-x*x` for `x` near 1 is awful, and the end result is still almost alright. You could argue that the containing expression compensates for the error of `1 - x*x` just like you argue that the containing expression makes it necessary to be precise near 1.

Comment: In general, we would want to consider diff(f(x), x) / abs(f(x)). For our f, abs(f(x)) is near 1 (in the [1, 2) binade) when x is near 1, so we can neglect it in that case. The fact that the derivative of f(x) goes to infinity means that the relative error goes to infinity to, when x is near 1. If we want to consider other regions of the domain, then we would want to consider diff(f(x), x) / abs(f(x)). However, then we ought to also be incorporating the nature of the errors in the calculations…

Comment: The computed result of `ArcTan(X, Sqrt(1-X*X))` is exactly the mathematical value of `ArcTan(X, Sqrt((1-X*X*(1+e0))*(1+e1))*(1+e2))*(1+e3)`, where each e0, e1, e2, and e3 is a value in [-2**-53, +2**-53], assuming that `Sqrt` and `ArcTan` are correctly-rounded implementations (reasonable for `Sqrt`, hard for `ArcTan`, but the error in `ArcTan` has no cascading effects, and we can relax the bound on e3 without affecting the analysis), and also neglecting denormals. Then we can analyze the effect on the final relative error of each of e0, e1, e2, and e3, and similarly for the `(1-X)*(1+X)` form.

Comment: We can see in those that it is not actually the derivative with respect to X that matters, but the derivative with respect to e0, e1, or e2. I.e., just as it is relative error in the final result that matters, it is relative errors in the intermediate calculations that lead to the final error, not absolute errors. I was able to ignore this complication in my answer since I only cared about X near 1 and f(x) in the 1 binade. I did not do a complete analysis in my answer because I wanted to focus on just the critical region that justifies using `(1-X)*(1+X)` instead of `1-X*X`.